# Find the tangent line of $y=x-e^{-x}$ parallel to $6x-2y=7$

Tags: calculus

Find the tangent line of $y=x-e^{-x}$ parallel to $6x-2y=7$

I know I have to take the derivative of the first equation, but I don’t know what to do after.

Comment: You want to know where the derivative of both equations match.

Answer (score 2):

The line $6x-2y = 7$ has slope $3$ thus, the tangent line to $y = x - e^{-x}$ that is parallel occurs when $1 + e^{-x} = 3$ or when $e^{-x} = 2 $ which means that $x = - \ln 2 $.

So you know you need to find the equation of the tangent line at the point $(- \ln 2, -2 - \ln 2 )$. Can you finish it?

Answer (score 1):

For two lines to be parallel, their slopes must equal. You can compute the slope of the tangent line of $x-e^x$ by taking the derivative. For the line L, put it in slope-intercept form. Call that slope m. Then you want to solve $f^\prime$(x) = m. Those are the x-values of the points on the graph of f(x) parallel to L.
Then you can use the point-slope formula to find the equation of the tangent lines.

Answer (score 0):

The tangent line of a function $f(x)$ at $(x_0,f(x_0))$ has the following form: $$y-f(x_0)=f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$$

We want to find a tangent line of $f(x)=x-e^{-x}$ that is parallel to $6x-2y=7$ or $y=3x-\frac{7}{2}$. All that is required for a line to be parallel to another line is their two slopes be equal. Hence we need $$f'(x_0)=3\implies(x-e^{-x})^{'}=3\implies1+e^{-x}=3\implies e^{-x}=2 $$ $$\implies\ln(e^{-x})=\ln(2)\implies-x=\ln(2)\space\text{or}\space x=-\ln(2)$$ We want the tangent line of $f(x)=x-e^{-x}$ at $x=-\ln(2)$.